# Send a POST XMLHttpRequest with a body to an express node server

Tags: node.js, http, post, express, xmlhttprequest

Basic background:

I have an express node server running a really simple website. The first page of the site has two inputs (1 text, 1 number)

```
<input type="text" name="xml_url" id="xml_in" placeholder="Required" />
<input type="number" min="0" name="c2" id="c2_in" placeholder="Required" />
```

As of right now really simple, the user inputs a url and a number, my app builds something and returns a link to a file.

My node server (basically) looks like this:

```
app.post('/secondPage', function(req, res){
 var url = req.body.xml_url
   , c2 = req.body.c2;
 //some stuff happens etc...
res.render('finalpage.html', {
    foo: c2andsomething
    url: newurl
 });
```

My Question/Issue:

I want to be able to not use my front end. I believe the code  will basically work (besides the render, I believe I will need something along the lines of

```
res.send(aJsonResponse); // obviously I will need to build the json
```

I just don't know how I can fake this post request. I'm sort of drawing a blank here. So far I've only really tried a few websites that claim they'll send a post request etc.. and tried in the browser just typing in my url with a query string, but my app doesn't accept GET..

Hopefully this wasn't too much rambling, but I would love to hear some suggestions. Will remove if this question makes no sense.

EDIT:

Okay so I always seem to jump the gun with these questions. I just tried in the console:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://192.168.1.1:3000/secondPage", true);
xmlhttp.send("foobar");
```

And I'm getting a CORS error.. I think I'll be able to figure this out here shortly, if you have any suggestions I would still really love to hear them.

Thanks

EDIT 2:

So I'm able to send the request and such no CORS issues.. but I'm not sure how to set the body in the request.

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://192.168.1.1:3000/secondPage", true);
 xmlhttp.send({"xml_in":"I-thought-this-was-the-body"});
```

but req.body is `{}`

Comment: i do this its through. "first argument must be a string or Buffer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved my issue using cURL, so not the best answer but here was what I used

```
curl -d "xml_in=http://google.com&c2=12345" http://192.168.1.1:3000/secondPage
```